# Is there a general formula for the number of subsets of a given size that can be created from a finite set?

Tags: combinatorics

I came upon the formula $(n^2-n)/2$, which gives the number of unique pairs from n elements. Am wondering if there is a general formula to achieve this for larger sized-subsets, i.e given 6 elements how many 3 member subsets can be made.

Comment: I believe you are looking for [combinations and the binomial coefficient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Answer (score 3):

${n \choose k }=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$, known as "$n$ choose $k$", is the number of ways of choosing $k$ elements from $n$.

Coincidentally (or not so coincidentally), and quite famously (at least among mathematicians) it is also the "binomial coefficient"...  you may wish to look it up.

Check that when $k=2$ we get your formula.

So, for $n=6$ and $k=3$, we get ${6\choose 3}=\frac{6!}{(6-3)!3!}=\frac{6!}{3!3!}=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot 4}{3!}=20$.

(Btw, it's pretty easy to see why...  For instance,  in the last example,  there are $6$ choices for the first element of the group,  then $5$ choices for the second,  and $4$ for the third.  This gives $6\cdot5\cdot4=120$.   But there are $6$ ways to "permute", or put the $3$ objects in different orders.  That's because we have $3$ choices for the first, $2$ for the second, and $1$ for the third.  So we divide by $6$, to arrive at $20$... 
groups or "combinations".)